# How to get the column index where the header matches some string?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to get column index of the `DataGridViewRow` where its header text matches the string "delete".

1. Can you please give me a hint?
2. How can I reach that by this expression:

   ```
   DataGridViewColumn c = new DataGridViewColumn();
   int index = Specialization_DataGridView.Columns.IndexOf(c.HeaderText.Where(/* dont know how to write expression where header text matches to "delete" */));
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set the `Name` and `HeaderText` properties of the `DataGridViewColumn` the same, then getting the index is simply:

```
int index = Specialization_DataGridView.Columns["delete"].Index;
```

If they are not the same, loop through the columns until you find it:

```
int index = -1;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in Specialization_DataGridView.Columns)
{
    if (col.HeaderText == "delete")
    {
        index = col.Index;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Extension:

```
<Extension>
    Public Sub DgvColumnNameByHeaderText(Dgv As DataGridView)
        Dim c As DataGridViewColumn
        With Dgv
            For Each c In Dgv.Columns
                c.Name = c.HeaderText
            Next
        End With
    End Sub

    ' Use: DataGridView1.DgvColumnNameByHeaderText()
```